# Scroll texts using bezel in Gear s2

Tags: scroll, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app

developing for **Gear s2** web app (Tizen),
how is it possible to scroll a page which has only text, using the bezel?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to listen to the "rotarydetent" events, e.g. like following:

```
document.addEventListener('rotarydetent', onRotarydetent); 
function onRotarydetent(ev) {
    var direction = ev.detail.direction;
    if(direction === "CW"){ // CW = clockwise; CCW = counterclockwise
        ... scroll down ... 
    } else {
        ... scrull up ...   
    }

}
```

So now to scroll the page content it depends on how build your web app. If you use the SDK Wizard and have a project including tau.js it will be simple if you know that tau adds a scroller container around each page. Now you just need to find the scroller and scroll it. Using jQuery it could look like following:

```
function onRotarydetent(ev) {
    var direction = ev.detail.direction,
        uiScroller = $('#pageid').find('.ui-scroller'),
        scrollPos = $(uiScroller).scrollTop();

    console.debug("onRotarydetent: " + direction);

    if(direction === "CW"){
        $(uiScroller).scrollTop(scrollPos + 100); // scroll down 100px
    } else {
        $(uiScroller).scrollTop(scrollPos - 100); // scroll up 100px
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the **UIComponents** sample app available within the Tizen Wearable SDK.

You need to use the **TAU library** to achieve Text scrolling using Beezel.

Create a new project using the **UI Components app** and Install it on **Gear s2 emulator or original hardware**. Then Run the app and **click** on the first option '**Header**' which contains your use case i.e. plain text scrollable by **beezel**.